# What are some of the the first examples of feats in D&D?

Tags: feats, dungeons-and-dragons, history-of-gaming, content-identification

I was ruminating over a book I owned a while ago, TSR's Celts Campaign Sourcebook for AD&D 2nd ed. Since I no longer have the copy I used to own I found a new (to me) one to read through it.

I remembered there were fighting techniques in this book, but what I was surprised to relearn was that these techniques are labeled as feats (see *Heroic Feats* on page 28)! They cost proficiencies (weapon and non-weapon) instead of substituting for ASIs like in 5th edition, and they largely seem to be very specific techniques (such as catching and throwing a spear, or running along the yoke-pole on a horse-drawn chariot while it's in motion). While I didn't have every 2nd edition book, I had quite a few, and can't remember feats in any other resource I owned, though that may just be my (lack of) memory.

**What are some of the first examples of feats in any edition of D&D?** Is this campaign book one of the first times we see feats? Were there other 2nd edition books with feats? Did feats come even earlier in D&Ds history?

Comment: TSR's Celt Campaign Sourcebook from... [1992?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celts_Campaign_Sourcebook)

Comment: @Trish Good question! Yes, 1992.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Celts Campaign Sourcebook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celts_Campaign_Sourcebook) was published in 1992 for AD&D 2nd Edition, and as our OP found, it had some sort of feat system. So it must have been invented before then. Since Dragonlance acted as some kind of *testbed* for TSR in some regards, I am looking at these adventure rules for evidence that can pin it down.

**DLA2 - Dragon Knight (TSR #9285)** was printed 1990 and has **"Special Skills"** for characters that follow the Dragon Knight class on page 59, granting (bonus) proficiencies, special maneuvers, and immunities:

> Level 1:
>
> • Dragon riding proficiency at no cost.
>
> • Uses a lance while on dragon-back with no flight to-hit
> penalty.
>
> • Immune to dragon awe.

**DL13 - Dragons of Despair (TSR #9176)** was printed 1986, and its Appendix does not refer to anything akin to feats. However, the bestiary does *describe* things that nowadays would be handled under a feat keyword, for example, page 33 says (in plaintext!):

> The first three types of draconians have
> wings, but only the Sivaks can truly fly. The
> three movement rates given are for walking,
> running while flapping wings, and gliding.

As a result, the first precursors of feats must have entered D&D **between 1986 and 1990.**